# Chess with Sudoku limitations

Tags: game-design, chess

The past few months I was working on a fun project which basically uses the traditional chess pieces and their move sets. On top of that I added Sudoku limitations to restrict movements. In order to make that work I also changed the board size to 9x9. In the following images you can see an example of how the restrictions affect the movements of bishops. Note how either of the bishops can't be in the same 1) row 2) column and 3) square as the other one:

[image][image]

---

Now, finally, my question:
Can anyone think of a good initial setup for all pieces? The traditional chess setup obviously doesn't work here thanks to the Sudoku restrictions.

**To make this answerable: the accepted answer will be the one closest to the traditional setup.**

<strike>On the one hand, I'd like to keep it as close as possible to the traditional setup. On the other hand, feel free to bring in your own ideas. Anything is possible! (Even placing pieces on the opponent's side of the board or multiple queens. Just saying...)

The one exception: there can only be 1 king of course (or maybe not?).</strike>

[Quick link to Wikipedia chess rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_chess#Initial_setup)

Comment: @ Avigrail, I think you have a great potential question here. But as is, it is a bit broad and likely to be closed. You may want to try narrowing down the scope a bit to make it a bit more directly answerable, and less idea generating.

Comment: What about the pawns? You'd need nine of them, and that means one of them would be on the Royal line, and one is promoting?

Comment: @VortexYT Yes, pawns are the major issue here. Using more than 3 pawns will make the setup grow towards the enemy quickly.

Comment: Is "make pawns exempt from the sudoku rules" a possibility?

Comment: @Malco Any idea how to make the question less broad? I stated the problem the way it is and honestly don't know how to edit it now...

Comment: @Avigrail Hmmm... it is a bit tough. One solution may be to present how you believe the pieces should be setup, with your reasoning, and ask potential strengths and weaknesses of that setup with bonus for how it might be improved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an exact answer for you here. Like any game in development you should test and iterate through different ideas in the search for the best one.

I'd come up with a solution you think is suitable, then go and play that game a few times. Does anything feel overpowered or wrong, then change it. You repeat this process until you get an ideal solution to the sitation.

Also well done for coming up with a really unique take on chess. For a game over 1000 years old it hasn't changed much since its origins, so it's impressive to see an honestly interesting take on a game that has such a well set up structure.